# USB boot on NTFS system, grub error: unknown filesystem

Tags: filesystems, boot, usb, grub

I followed online instructions on setting up a USB bootdisk with rufus-3.3 to install Linux Manjaro, after setting everything up I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

So far two versions of the Manjaro - from *Manjaro.org* -  I've used poop out the same error, but I cant tell if they're the problem or.... my system.

My system is a windows 10 NTFS setup on UEFI/GPT

Any insight?

Thanks

Comment: are you using an encrypted file system?

Comment: not to my knowledge

Comment: I'm going to try another version of Linux, Xubuntu to verify whether or not my system is corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the issue is with the current version of Rufus 3.3 not having the most up to date Grub (ships with 2.02 when the .iso i'm installing requires Grub 2.03.1)

Rufus has a solution built into the app however. Once it detects something called a "ISOHybrid image" an option comes up called DD mode, where the program writes your USB bootdisk as a Disk image rather than a "file copy"  --- the difference being that the latter gives you full access to the USB after writing it.

in any case, I'm told from the Manjaro.org forum the answer is DD mode.

(href: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-problem-in-booting-grub-usb-install/32174/9)